# Overloading a property's set method

Tags: vb.net

ok, maybe it's not a method exactly.  here's what I'd like to do:

```
Private _Columns As ArrayList
Public Property Columns() As ArrayList
    Get
       Return _Columns
    End Get
    Set(Cols As ArrayList)
       _Columns = Cols
    End Set
    Set(Cols As MyOwnList)
       _Columns = New ArrayList
       For Each o As MyObj in Cols
          _Columns.Add(o.Column)
       Next
    End Set
End Property
```

which would allow me to conveniently set the property by assigning to it various kinds of collection types... except, I can't do it because apparently the *Set* method has to take an argument of the type of the property itself...  I get the complaint:

> 'Set' parameter must have the same type as the containing property

is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to Overload a Property in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238048/is-there-a-way-to-overload-a-property-in-net)

Comment: I wouldn't do this... Just write it as a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really overloading but the following could offer a (temporary) workaround:

```
Private Cols As ArrayList
Public Property Columns() As ArrayList
    Get
        Return _Columns
    End Get
    Set(Cols As ArrayList)
        _Columns = Cols
    End Set
End Property

Public WriteOnly Property SpecializedColumns() As MyOwnList
    Set(value As MyOwnList)
        Dim list As New ArrayList
        For Each o As MyObj In value
            list.Add(o.Column)
        Next
        Columns = list
    End Set
End Property
```

I think this is as close as you can get to real overloaded properties...

**EDIT**

I believe the proper way to do what you're trying to achieve is to define a `ToArrayList()` method on your `MyOwnList` class.

```
Public Function ToArrayList()
    Dim list As New ArrayList

    For Each o As MyObj In Me.Items
        list.Add(o.Column)
    Next

    Return list
End Function
```

and set your property like this:

```
    Columns = theMyOwnListObject.ToArrayList
```

If you don't have access to the source code of the class, you can still achieve this through extension methods.

Comment: you're quite correct regarding the appropriateness of the second approach.  I don't actually own MyOwnList so I can't modify it and even if it were declared as Partial, I couldn't extend it because it goes into a separate assembly... so I'm out of luck there... but the first approach will work.  thanks!

Comment: If you're using VS2008 or later then you can declare the method as an extension method in a module. No need for the class to be partial, nor does it need to be in the same assembly. Excellent article that helped me to get started with extensions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163317.aspx

Comment: StevenDotNet: awesome! I actually forgot I've already written extension methods so thanks, this will be a great help in many other ways as I'm working with an existing framework that I can't touch

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the type of the parameter expected by the Setter in your auto-property.

However, you could supply your own implicit casting function for MyOwnList from your example and then it would automatically be converted into an ArrayList when you pass it in to the setter.

```
Class MyOwnList
    ' your class code here....
    ' 
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal p1 As MyOwnList) As ArrayList
        Dim columns As New ArrayList   
       For Each o As MyObj in p1
          columns.Add(o.Column)   
       Next 
     return columns  
    End Operator 
End Class
```

Then elsewhere in your program this code would work:

```
Dim myList as new MyOwnList
SomeClass.Columns = myList
```

Comment: I love that!  sadly I can't use it as I cannot modify MyOwnList (it's not really mine) but you get a point for an excellent suggestion.  thanks.